# Combine two columns from different files into one table side-by-side using bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files,from which I am trying to extract the third column from each file and combine them together.How to combine them into one table side-by-side?

```
file1="maize.txt"
file2="wheat.txt"

awk -F '{print $3}' file1
awk -F '{print $3}' file2

"wheat.txt"
chr -   b73_chr10   B73-Chr10   0   150189435       
chr -   w22_chr7    W22-Chr7    0   176764762       
chr -   w22_chr8    W22-Chr8    0   175793759       

"maize.txt"
chr -   w22_chr9    W22-Chr9    0   156750706       
chr -   w22_chr10   W22-Chr10   0   150189435       
chr -   w22_chr6    W22-Chr6    0   169174353   

Output : 

b73_chr10   w22_chr9
w22_chr7    w22_chr10
w22_chr8    w22_chr6
```

Comment: What output do you want to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$3; next} {print a[FNR], $3}' wheat.txt maize.txt
b73_chr10   w22_chr9
w22_chr7    w22_chr10
w22_chr8    w22_chr6
```

Comment: Hi,I tried the same code for another 2 files,but now it is just saving the first row and not going to next line.

Comment: There must be some difference in file data structure otherwise it is pretty simple awk command

Comment: Okk..Sure.I will check it out.

Comment: How do you use it for more than 20-30 files

Comment: Can be done easily. Do you have a question for that?

Comment: @anubhava: smart code. can you please elaborate how to do this for several files, all with same name, each being in a separate subdirectory?

Comment: Do you know how many files you want to combine or that is dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

The tool you're looking for is `paste`.  You can write a function to extract the 3rd field as you defined above.

```
$ f3() { awk '{print $3}' "$1"; }; paste <(f3 wheat.txt) <(f3 maize.txt)

b73_chr10       w22_chr9
w22_chr7        w22_chr10
w22_chr8        w22_chr6
```

Comment: I like the way you use a function. You should quote `"$1"` though